# OrientDB no return for reading outgoing edges of vertices

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm trying to read edges I previously added to the DB:

```
Iterable<Vertex> startNodes = getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getStartNode(), graph);
            Iterable<Vertex> endNodes = getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getEndNode(), graph);

            List<Edge> list = StreamSupport.stream(startNodes.spliterator(), false)
                    .flatMap(vertex1 -> StreamSupport.stream(vertex1.getEdges(Direction.OUT, relationshipId).spliterator(), false))
                    .filter(edge -> StreamSupport.stream(endNodes.spliterator(), false).anyMatch(vertex -> edge.getVertex(Direction.IN).equals(vertex)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm creating the following manner:

```
Iterable<Vertex> startNodes = this.getVertexList(storage.getStartNode(), graph);
        Iterable<Vertex> endNodes = this.getVertexList(storage.getEndNode(), graph);

        for (Vertex startNode : startNodes)
        {
            for (Vertex endNode : endNodes)
            {
                String edgeClass = "class:" + storage.getId();
                Edge edge = startNode.addEdge(edgeClass, endNode);

                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : storage.getProperties().entrySet())
                {
                    edge.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
                edge.setProperty(Constants.TAG_HASH, HashCreator.sha1FromRelationship(storage));
                edge.setProperty(Constants.TAG_SNAPSHOT_ID, snapshotId);
            }
        }
        graph.commit();
```

But It seems like the return is always empty because the return of the first `vertex1.getEdges(Direction.OUT, relationshipId)` is null.
Strangely it is not null if I use `Direction.IN` but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Could you post all code to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: https://github.com/Raycoms/thesis/blob/master/src/main/java/main/java/com/bag/server/database/OrientDBDatabaseAccess.java

Comment: Is there a way to do this @AlessandroRota ?